# Rendering problem: Messy render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, mesh, uv, topology

[image]

What could be the cause of these rendering problem? I use Blender 2.82. And I tried everything I know to fix it but the problem still persist. Anyone can help me about this? thank you. I use cycles to render.

Comment: Are you using cycles or eevee ?

Comment: I'm using cycles.

Comment: Then try increasing the poly count of the glass thingy, or use subsurface scattering. That will help.

Comment: Do we speak about rendering or baking? Share this red part in simplified file (only parts that matters to produce this) via https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: maybe try Properties panel > Object Data > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data?

Comment: This looks like possibly two meshes are closely intersecting each other, especially if when you move the viewport, the red and black mixture glitches around. That means two faces are in exactly the same mathematical position, and cycles will not know what to do with that.